# Change encoding body with alamofire

Tags: json, swift, swift3, encoding, alamofire

I need to change how my body is send to my server actually with this code

```
        let parameters: Parameters = [
        "users": array
    ]
    print(parameters)

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ApiSvain.header)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
    }
```

Array is [String]

When I print that I got in **xcodeDebug**:

> ["users": ["5ab4305e30c73c4aa140aa06", "5ab4324c30c73c4aa140aa07", "5ab432fe30c73c4aa140aa08"]]

But in my **backend** I got(Node/express):

> [ '5ab4305e30c73c4aa140aa06',
>     '5ab4324c30c73c4aa140aa07',
>     '5ab432fe30c73c4aa140aa08' ]

Simple quote and \n between elements, I need to have in backend that result:

> "5ab4305e30c73c4aa140aa06", "5ab4324c30c73c4aa140aa07", "5ab432fe30c73c4aa140aa08"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own URLRequest and pass it to Alamofire for HTTP Communication.

So if you want to sent array of strings to server as json format. Just create a URLRequest with your URL and set httpBody for Request as serialised array as Data format. This URL request can be directly loaded to Alamofire

Please refer code below.

```
    let array = ["5ab4305e30c73c4aa140aa06", "5ab4324c30c73c4aa140aa07", "5ab432fe30c73c4aa140aa08" ]
    var urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: "YOUR_URL_STRING")!)
    if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: []) {
        urlRequest.httpBody = data
    }


    Alamofire.request(urlRequest)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
    }
```

Comment: Note working I got an alamofire, console tell me my url is not good with your method. I think I just need to change the property of encoding when I call alamofire